# Creating hashMap for 2d arrays

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I am working on a problem in which I have chess board-states represented as 2d arrays.
I need the ability to see if the current board-state I am working with has been seen before.

I thought of using a HashMap object that takes a 2d array as an argument and then creates its unique hash value. Then I can see if the HashMap object contains whichever board state I am currently working with by using HashMap's ".contains()" method.

What I am confused about is that the HashMap object takes "key" and "value" arguments. 
I just need an object that simply takes in a 2d array as an argument and creates its unique hash value, and then allows me to use ".contains()" and ".put()" methods.

I'm getting the feeling that I don't really understand hashMaps properly, so where am I getting confused?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you need a `Set`, not a `Map`. A `Map` is, as you say, a key-value structure. Since you only need to store the values (hash codes), a `Set` is all you need. To get fast lookups, a `HashSet` is probably your best bet.

Just calculate the hash code for each state, check if it exists in your `HashSet`, otherwise add it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array wrapper which will implement hashcode and equals for array

```
class ArrayHolder {
    int[][] a;

    public ArrayHolder(int[][] a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof ArrayHolder)) {
            return false;
        }
        return Arrays.deepEquals(a, ((ArrayHolder)obj).a);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.deepHashCode(a); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need a 2D array, with a single 1D array you can put all the information in the same place, in a very easy way, less complicated. Why don't use a String to store your board state and just use an array of string to store all the board states?
I think it's important to not use a Set as you can repeat your board state if, for example, both players repeat movements.
If you don't need to store repeated board states, you can use Set and the set.add method, which will tell you wether the String it's already in the Set or not.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you board entity in a class named Board. Override hashCode and equals methods to work in your case. Use HashSet then.

**Suggestion:** May be not the fastest, but definetelly the easiest way to write equals/hashCode is to convert your board to String and delegate work to String methods. (Autogeneration in your favourite IDE will also do fine).